# Raspberry pi 3 model b+ datasheet

Tags: pi-3

I recently bought a Raspberry 3 model B+ but I couldn't find the detailed datasheet of the board. Googling "Raspberry pi 3 B+" didn't really help.
Could you please help me get it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "detailed datasheet"?  Have you looked at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/README.md ?

Comment: I mean where I can see the pin assignment, the description of different peripherals, ext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Pis with the 40 pin expansion header have the same pinout.

See e.g. https://pinout.xyz/

All the SoC (System On a Chip) hardware peripherals are identical on all Pi models.

See [BCM2835 ARM Peripherals](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2835/BCM2835-ARM-Peripherals.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you search for is this: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/datasheet.md

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think you're pointing to the wrong thing (compute module) whereas the OP will find the datasheet for the Pi 3+ here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md

Comment: You are right !